# Losing connection to device during start with Android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm having problems with setting up my Mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy J5) to work as my Test-Device for flutter in android studio.
I in-between managed to start my app on my phone but always lost connection after a while. Today it won't start up at all without any changes in the settings. 
The output in the console of android studio looks as follows

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM J510FN in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
error: device '933fecf1' not found
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 255
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device '933fecf1' not found

error: device '933fecf1' not found
- waiting for device -
Error launching application on SM J510FN.
```

I've seen the android studio losing connection to my phone while trying to install the app.apk. As the connection hasn't been steady at any point since I started getting in touch with flutter and android studio I guess there might be an issue with the adb but I have no clue how to track it down.

**Flutter Doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: try `adb kill-server` and check if the output of `adb devices -l` prints anything suspicious.

Comment: add kill-server didn't help.
adb devices -l shows:
List of devices attached
933fecf1               device usb:337641472X product:j5xnltexx model:SM_J510FN device:j5xnlte transport_id:30

Comment: Some people reported similar issue a while back but not obvious solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14604

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for my problem and want to share nevertheless it seems it a little too simple: I was using a defect USB cable. Changing to a newer cable solved all connection problems immediately.. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Didn't help for me (

Answer (score 4):

For me it was solved as I disabled "Use libusb backend" for "Android Debug Bridge (adb) in the settings:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

My problem's gone (on Windows 10) after I installed google USB drivers from tools -> SDK Manager in Android Studio, turned off USB Powers saving in Control Panel -> Power Management and turned off "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in all my USB-Controllers in Windows device manager.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old topic, but the problem seems to still be here. In my case after update of platform-tools (macosx).
None of above, and all other advices (like manually adb kill-server, adb start-server, adb -d install... etc - didn't work)

The only way I've found - is do downgrade the platform-tools back.
I've used the link like this:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-darwin.zip
But it can be reformatted to any version and any platform.. for example:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip

And after that, everything starts to work as before.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 -When I connect my device and started the **flutter** project run, the device automatically asks to enable debug mode even I have enabled it already. And then I press ok device disconnects and in few seconds it connects automatically.

Case 2 -When I connect my device and started the **flutter** project run, the device is connected and disconnect continually.

Case 3-When I connect my device and started the **Native** project run, the device is connected and the **native** project runs in the device.

> I checked all most all the solutions in stack-over-flow and medium.
> But nothing worked for me.

*But there are two solutions I have recognized.*

> 1. Start/Open a native project and then start/open your flutter project. then the device won't disconnect.
> 2. Start/Open your flutter project if the device is disconnecting from any of the above three cases. restart the android studio and
>    check if it is working, if not restart again...

Answer (score 0):

I use.
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 20
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, org.intellij.plugins.markdown

I was have same problem I use Samsung Galaxy A 10. I download Android USB Driver for Windows v.1.7.43. I installed this drivers.

And problem was  deasappear.

Answer (score -2):

If your using USB cable then try with a new cable or use ADB WiFi plugin

Comment: There is already an accepted answer which is basically what you suggested. Please read the previous answers and see if you are contributing a new solution or an improvement to an existing answer.